# laravel + react not loading React's stuff with localhost (without php artisan serve)

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel-5, react-router, xampp

Is it possible to run Laravel + react with some thing like http://localhost/projectfolder/public

without `php artisan server`

Than was may landing app.jsx code

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                        <Route exact path="/forgot" component={Forgot} />
                        <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects} />
                        <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                        <Route exact path="/projects/create" component={CreateProject} />
                        <Route exact path="/projects/:id" component={ShowProject} />
                        <Route exact path="/projects3D/:id" component={ShowProject3D} />
                        <Route exact path="/projects/:id/edit" component={CreateProject} />
                        <Route exact path="/projects/s/:id/edit" component={ProjectSections} />
                        <Route exact path="/report/error" component={ReportError} />
                        <Route exact path="/projects/:id/report" component={Report} />
                    </Switch>
            </Router>
            )
    }
}
```

Adding `/projectfolder/public` in Route component helped me to resolve.

Which was my mistake i guess.

Comment: Surely, you did some research on this matter, yourself? Please share your efforts and more details.

Comment: @jasie review what i found or mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `/projectfolder/public` in Route component helped me to resolve.

```
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/" component={Login} />
<Route path="/projectfolder/public/login" component={Login} />
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/register" component={Register} />
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/forgot" component={Forgot} />
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/projects" component={Projects} />
<Route path="/projectfolder/public/profile" component={Profile} />
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/projects/create" component={CreateProject} />
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/projects/:id" component={ShowProject} />
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/projects3D/:id" component={ShowProject3D} />
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/projects/:id/edit" component={CreateProject} />
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/projects/s/:id/edit" component={ProjectSections} />
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/report/error" component={ReportError} />
<Route exact path="/projectfolder/public/projects/:id/report" component={Report} />
```

Which was my mistake i guess.